# TCL: \. is not working as expected

Tags: tcl

I have the below code

```
set src "/tmp/16.10c.00.01/run.c"
regsub "\.c" $src ".o" obj
puts "$obj"
```

It is printing `/tmp/16.1.o.00.01/run.c` as output.
where in expected output is `/tmp/16.10c.00.01/run.o`.
If I keep it as `"\.c$"` it is working as expected.
what is wrong in the first code.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong is that the raw regular expression being passed to the interpreter is being:

```
.c
```

The above in regex means any character followed by `c`.

What you need to do is to use double backslashes, the first to escape the second backslash. That or use braces for quotation (which prevent the first substitution):

```
regsub "\\.c" $src ".o" obj
# or
regsub {\.c} $src ".o" obj
```

Comment: how is ".c" different from "\.c"

Comment: @Rupesh In regex, `.` matches any one character (it is a wildcard). If you want to match a dot, you need to escape the `.` because otherwise it will act as a wildcard.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say. My point of view is only from double quotes. In double quotes to escape dot we have to put "\." and to escape \ we have to rewrite it as "\\.".  My understanding is regex ".c" and "\.c" are same in terms of  functionality. Though they are different.  Am I right?

Comment: You are confusing escaping in tcl string with escaping in regex. '.c' means <anything> followed by 'c'. '\.c' means '.' followed by 'c' (dot is escaped by '\', loses special powers). But tcl (and other languages) uses backslash for its own escaping in double quotes (plain strings), which is why you have to write either "\\.c" or {\.c}. Braces are recommended for regexes (less quoting). And you might want {\.c$}, the '$' means <end of string>.

Comment: @Rupesh Sorry I didn't get notified of your comment. Misoslav summarises it well. See if that makes it any clearer?